# Не получается записать значения команды в переменную в makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

Нужно записать значения выполнения в переменную в Makefile для дальнейшего использования, но почему-то постоянно пустая строка, перепробовал разные способы, уже попросту трачу время в пустую, не могу понять в чём проблема так как в консоли сама команда работает, но в переменой постоянно пустота, пример объявления:

```
#VARIABLES
var = $(echo $(date +%s | md5sum | head -c${1:-32};echo ;))

test:
    echo "$(var)";
```

Если код выше не рабочий вариант, то возможно есть вариант как написать аналог, для генерации уникального хеша который будет работать в Makefail, ну конечно хотелось бы разобраться почему код выше именно при выполнении make команды не работает...

Comment: `var := $(shell echo ....)`  Но вообще вы делаете что не то

Comment: В частности `${1:-32}` это какой-то башизм, который не имеет смысла в мейкфайле

Comment: З shell не заработало, что до  ```head -c${1:-32}``` нужно для получения именно хеша строки без других символов

Comment: Но в тому что делаю что-то не то даже спорить не буду, если делал что нужно, тогда и вопроса не создавал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если цель просто сгенерить случайную строку, то можно глянуть на ответы тут https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string

Если просто исправить ваш код, то будет примерно так:

```
var := $(shell date +%s | md5sum | head -c32)

test:
    echo "$(var)"
```

Выражение `${1:-32}` это [default substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) в bash и не имеет никакого смысла внутри Makefile, так что я его просто заменил на дефолтное значение — `32`.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо не до конца разобрался.